# getloadavg() within kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, cpu-usage

Is there an equivalent api like getloadavg() that can be used within the kernel i.e. for my own driver ?

I have a driver that is thrashing and I would like to throttle it, and i am looking for a kernel-api to find about the cpu usage.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for the `get_avenrun()` function in `kernel/sched.c`. An example of how to use it is in `fs/proc/loadavg.c`:

```
static int loadavg_proc_show(struct seq_file *m, void *v)
{
        unsigned long avnrun[3];

        get_avenrun(avnrun, FIXED_1/200, 0); 

        seq_printf(m, "%lu.%02lu %lu.%02lu %lu.%02lu %ld/%d %d\n",
                LOAD_INT(avnrun[0]), LOAD_FRAC(avnrun[0]),
                LOAD_INT(avnrun[1]), LOAD_FRAC(avnrun[1]),
                LOAD_INT(avnrun[2]), LOAD_FRAC(avnrun[2]),
                nr_running(), nr_threads,
                task_active_pid_ns(current)->last_pid);
        return 0;
}
```

Though I'm a little skeptical of how you can use the load average to modify a driver -- the load average is best treated as a heuristic for system administrators to gauge how their system *changes* over time, not necessarily how "healthy" it might be at any given moment -- what specifically in the driver is causing troubles? There's probably a better mechanism to make it play nicely with the rest of the system.

Comment: If you are asking for more context to my problem, here you go. This kernel module handles network notifications and now it needs to scale from hundred notifications to 1000 notifications in bursts, this results in CPU hogging.The handling part is n^2 complexity and it takes more time to handle for some of the notifications (not necessarily the last ones). Hence I would like the module to "pace" itself while handling these changes depending on the CPU usage. If loadavg() is not the right place for this scenario, what else should i be looking at ?

Comment: Ah, that does sound like a sticky situation. Are you holding locks too long? Can you re-formulate the core loop of your code to periodically drop and re-acquire locks to allow the code to be pre-empted or otherwise "share" the CPU? Or could you offload work to the workqueue? (See `Documentation/workqueue.txt`.)

Comment: I am not holding any locks, the dev driver redraws the best network topology based on these notifications and passes the info to other drivers and daemons. But I have verified that a staged handling of these notifications helps solve the problem. Thank you for your prompt answers !!